# vaadin tooltip not showing in dialog

Tags: java, tooltip, vaadin, vaadin-flow

There is a baseview class inherited from VerticalLayout, in which a TextField and Tooltip are created with binding to a TextField. When using baseview in a class inherited from Dialog, the tooltip is not shown.

example:
UPD: updated the example to a lighter one

```
@Route(value = "Future", layout = MainLayout.class)
@RouteAlias(value = "/Future", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class FutureView extends VerticalLayout {

    BaseForm form;
    public FutureView() {
        form = new BaseForm();
        this.setSizeFull();
        form.open();
        
        Button btn = new Button("Open form");
        btn.addClickListener(e->form.open());
        
        add(btn,form);
    }
}

class BaseForm extends Dialog {
    Tooltip tooltip;
    TextField text;
    
    public BaseForm() {
        text= new TextField();
        text.setReadOnly(true);
    
        tooltip= new Tooltip();
        tooltip.attachToComponent(text);
        tooltip.add(new Span("Some"));
        add(text,tooltip);
    }
}
```

If the form is opened in the constructor, then the tooltip works, but if you close and reopen the form, it stops working

Tooltip: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tooltip

Comment: I think this should be added as bug report to https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/vcf-tooltip/issues

Comment: As a reference, the issue is currently tracked here: https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/tooltip/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, using a script in the BaseForm.java class helped me.

if you do not open the form in the constructor, the script will not work

```
text.setId("target");
tooltip.setId("tooltip");
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("document.getElementById('target').onmouseover = function(){"
            + "document.getElementById('tooltip').removeAttribute('hidden');"
            + "};"
            + "document.getElementById('target').onmouseleave = function(){"
            + "document.getElementById('tooltip').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');"
            + "};"
            + "window.onload = function(){"
            + "document.getElementById('overlay').removeAttribute('opened');"
            + "document.getElementById('overlay').setAttribute('closing', 'true');"
            + "};");
```